# how to designed a specific shape of scrollView

Tags: ios

How iOS we can to achieve a specific shape of the scrollView, the system provides graphical shape of scrollView.

I want to achieve scrollView in a hexagonal or circular shape, Is there some design ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // self is the scroll view
    layer.frame = self.bounds;

    // here is a circular arc
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2) radius:self.bounds.size.width / 2.5 startAngle:-3 / 4 * M_PI endAngle:1 / 3 * M_PI clockwise:YES];
    layer.lineWidth = 20;
    layer.path = path.CGPath;

layer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
self.layer.mask = layer;
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: i write to code in - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;then i call